# Matlab script input a table of cells from the keyboard

Tags: matlab

I have a script that creates a cell array,with values got from the keyboard, and than call a function that returns me the number of elements that are a matrix or a scalar. How could I do it?
I need a script that allows the user to input something with a structure like this:

```
A = 
 [3x3 double] ’Anne Smith’ 
 [3.0000+ 7.0000i] [1x21 double]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "input a table of cells from the keyboard"?

Comment: I have to make a script that ask the user to create the table of cells, element-by-element.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html ?